# Text to row in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the attached data which i want to convert the same into row wise.....

Is there any suggested solution for the same....

Invoice number
"729775
20092411222
160370
2009300732
337617
162521
809751
843291
848311
0363341"

Invoice Amount
" 10,000,000.00 
 5,000,000.00 
 5,000,000.00 
 5,000,000.00 
 10,000,000.00 
 10,000,000.00 
 15,000,000.00 
 5,000,000.00 
 8,000,000.00 
 5,000,000.00 "

Invoice Date
"31-Aug-09
31-Aug-09
25-Sep-09
27-Oct-09
26-Nov-09
24-Dec-09
29-Jan-10
29-Mar-10
6-Apr-10
28-Sep-10"

Comment: how i can attached the excel file?????????? any suggestions

Comment: i can make clear the same with attachemnet

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Excel 2007 right now, but the procedure shouldn't be substantially different from 2010. Basically, you'll want to copy your data into a cell like so:

[image]

Select Text-to-columns on the Data tab and follow the wizard. You'll want to select "delimited" as the data type. Because your data is separated by spaces, make sure the wizard has spaces set as the delimiter. Then set the data in the cells to type "general" and finish:

[image]

If you need to transpose the data (swap rows with columns) you can copy the  data and use the paste special option, selecting "transpose.

Comment: You don't need to repeat for each line.  You can simply do this process on several cells at once, or even on the entire column.  Very detailed answer, but you might want to consider redoing the pics so only the relevant parts are showing (hint: `Alt+PrntScrn` will capture just the active window).

Comment: Thank you muchly. Edited (mostly) as suggested. Still not perfect, but it's more readable now.

Comment: its not so simple as I have copy paste in the main body... it is showing continous /... but in excel it is written in a celll..... that why i m asking for the attachment of file,.... so that i can attach the excel file & make it more clear...